# wordpress wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Why I can't add an id or a class in the output of wp_nav_menu?

here is my code:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_id' => 'navigation', 'container_class' => 'menu' ) );
```

nothing happens on this.

I already added it to registered items in functions.php

Comment: Show us what the html-output is and what your functions.php looks like.

Comment: Could you also post the code you're using the register the menu? The reason I'm asking is that if your menu is empty and since you're not specifying the `theme_location` parameter, WordPress may default to the `fallback_cb` you specified when registering the menu. If you didn't, it would default to `wp_page_menu` which will ignore your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the WP Super Cache plugin? You will need to turn it off while you are changing/developing things.  Also, some themes don't always support menus in the way you might expect.

Comment: I am also facing problem what's the next ? wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container'   => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
    'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
   ));